# Cross-domain AJAX using jsonp and .NET Web Service over SSL/HTTPS

Tags: .net, jquery, web-services, jsonp

I am using the example below to do a cross-domain ajax call using .net web services and jquery.
http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/adelkhalil/archive/2009/08/14/cross-domain-jsonp-with-jquery-call-step-by-step-guide.aspx

It works fine until I try to change my endpoint to https.  I don't get any errors, just no response.  My first question would be, is it even possible to do with jsonp?  If so, I would appreciate some guidance on how to troubleshoot/fix the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get a response when you perform the https transaction manually?

Comment: Are you trying to access an account with a robot https (web)?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I just tested this and it's working now.  Unfortunately I can't explain why it wasn't before.  Maybe a simple mistake that I missed somewhere.

Comment: That's to bad you don't have a definite solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jsonp works the same with http and https.

You might have lost Your session or modified the environment somehow else.

Comment: Actually I think you may be right.  I think maybe the call to the web service was over http while my authenticated session was https.

Comment: Or session cookie was not sent due to the protocol change. I'm not sure how it works. Would have to check. But if so - the problem might be more common.